# How do I unit test logic in a Hapi 'onPreResponse' callback function using Jest?

Tags: jestjs, hapi.js, hapi

How do I unit test logic in a Hapi 'onPreResponse' callback function using Jest?

I am seeking 100% code coverage, but this "if" path below isn't hit.

Code to test:

```
module.exports = {
    async initialize() {
        const server = await Glue.compose(manifest);

        server.route(routes);

        server.ext('onPreResponse', function (request, h) {
            var response = request.response;
            if (response && response.isServer && response.isBoom) {
                const error = response.error || response.message;
                server.log(['error'], error);
            }
            return h.continue;
        });

        return server;
    }
};
```

**Test case:**

```
Given a particular route is called,
When the handler throws an error
Then onPreResponse should log the error
```

Comment: What's `Glue` ?

Comment: Glue is part of the Hapi ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

I followed this example: https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/test/handler.js#L139-L160

Basically what I do is:

- I create a test server.
- I import the route that includes the onPreResponse extension.
- I write the handler depending on what I want to test.
- I call the route using the server.inject

Here is an example:

```
const myRoute = require( '../myroute' );
lab.it( 'onPreResponse with client badrequest, async () => {
    const testServer = Hapi.server();
    const route = {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/my/path',
        options: { ext: myRoute.ext },
    };

    testServer.route( { ...route, handler: () => {
        return Boom.badRequest( 'Bad request' );
    } } );

    const res = await testServer.inject({method: "GET", "url": "/my/path" } );
    Code.expect( res.statusCode ).to.equal( 400 );
    Code.expect( res.result.error.message ).to.include( 'Bad request' );
} );
```